React Native: Prevent Swipeable from Blocking Horizontal Tab Swipes in TabNavigator
I'm building a screen in React Native that contains a list of Swipeable cards, where each card can be swiped to the right to reveal actions. However, this screen is part of a TabNavigator, and the issue is that the Swipeable component from react-native-gesture-handler is blocking horizontal swipes intended for switching between tabs.
The Behavior I Need:
Swipeable cards should be swipeable to the right to reveal actions.
Horizontal swipes to switch between tabs should not be blocked by the Swipeable component when the user swipes to the left.
Problem:
Currently, the Swipeable component is intercepting all horizontal swipe gestures, even when the user is trying to swipe to another tab in the TabNavigator.
My Attempts So Far:
I have tried using PanResponder to detect horizontal swipes and disable the Swipeable component during those gestures. However, this doesn't seem to prevent the issue, as the Swipeable still captures horizontal swipes intended for tab navigation.
My Question:
How can I allow the user to swipe left to navigate between tabs in the TabNavigator without Swipeable intercepting the gesture?
Is there a better way to manage swipe gestures for both the Swipeable cards and the tab navigation at the same time?
Code of Swipeable:
<Swipeable
  renderRightActions={() => (
    <View style={styles.swipeableContainer}>
      <Legend />
    </View>
  )}
>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(item)}>
    <GenericPlannedShipmentCard key={item.shipmentId} {...item} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</Swipeable>

Code of the custom tab navigator:
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import { ActiveTab, GenericTabNavigatorProps } from './genericTabNavigatorTypes';
import { I18nManager, View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { colors } from '../../constants/colors';
import { styles } from './styles';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const GenericTabNavigator: React.FC<GenericTabNavigatorProps> = ({
  tabs,
  initialRouteName,
  setActiveTab,
}) => {
  I18nManager.swapLeftAndRightInRTL(true);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Tab.Navigator
        style={styles.tabBarNavigator}
        initialRouteName={initialRouteName}
        sceneContainerStyle={styles.tabBarSceneContainer}
        screenOptions={{
          lazy: true,
          tabBarActiveTintColor: colors.text.primaryBlue,
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: colors.text.darkGrey,
          tabBarStyle: styles.tabBar,
          tabBarIndicatorContainerStyle: styles.tabBarIndicatorContainer,
          tabBarIndicatorStyle: styles.tabBarIndicator,
          tabBarContentContainerStyle: styles.tabBarContentContainer,
        }}>
        {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
          <Tab.Screen
            key={index}
            name={tab.name}
            component={tab.component}
            options={({navigation}) => {
              return {
                tabBarLabel: navigation.isFocused()
                  ? tab.activeLabel
                  : tab.label,
                tabBarLabelStyle: navigation.isFocused()
                  ? styles.tabLabel
                  : styles.tabLabelUnActive,
              };
            }}
            listeners={() => ({
              focus: () => {
                setActiveTab?.(tab.name as ActiveTab);
              },
            })}
          />
        ))}
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </View>
  );
};

export default GenericTabNavigator;


Since this is a UI issue, can you share the minimum reproducible expo snack?
